# Any other GXT themes?

Tags: java, gwt, extjs, gxt

The GXT themes which come by default are ok but they're all essentially versions of the same thing with different colors. Looking around I can't find any attractive commercial or free themes.

Is there a good place to find new themes or has a third party market failed to emerge so far?

Comment: I would **LOVE** for someone from Sencha to comment on this.

Comment: I guess that as of now the answer is no. It's a shame because it'd be great to have themes following the current web app trends. I've actually ended up implementing some theming in my app to try and make it look a little less "desktop".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently a set themes for GWT really very small. There are several ways to solve this problem: First, you can use additional libraries, such as SmartGWT or ExtGWT, which provide a list of components and their own set of skins. The second way is to override the styles of GWT-components in your CSS file.
In my projects, I use both of these approaches. Using the library, I expand the list of available components, and changing styles with the help of CSS-file, which override the GWT-component classes and Ids.

Comment: Using a CSS file can also be useful when your GWT-application is composed of many modules, and you have to set them all the same styles. Also, when you want to go back to the standard skin, you simply unplug your CSS.

Comment: The question asks about GXT themes, but you refer to SmartGWT and old ExtGWT.

Comment: In first sentence of my answer I told that there is pretty small list of GWT themes provided. And I described alternative approaches which can be helpful for someone.

Comment: But the user's question is GXT specific and your first sentence references GWT. Also mixing SmartGWT with just about any other custom GWT , you can do it, but there be dragons :( SmartGWT and it's canvases ...

Comment: rjdkolb, I faces with projects where SmartGWT was mixed with custom GWT - it was REALLY beastly. Basically, it were projects with legacy code, where new dev team tried to implement new features with new trendy libs, and they were not going to rewrite the old code. E.g. I remember, that one project contained half of it on Vaadin, and second one part - on SmartGWT. And it was not a good approach.